# Difference between よる/よって

Tags: english-to-japanese

> A: 事故**による**死者が増えている。
>   B: 帰る時間は、曜日**によって**違います。
>   C: 佐藤さん**によれば**、田中さんは会社をやめるということです。
>   D: 関西空港はイタリア人**によって**設計されました。

Comment: It is generally expected that you provide an attempt at translating your sentences and that you explain your thought processes. This is to demonstrate that you've made an attempt to solve the problem yourself and to give us an understanding of your level of ability. Please consider this in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

> 事故による死者が増えている。
>   Casualties due to accidents are increasing.

In this sentence による acts like (is?) a verb. It is used in a relative clause which is modifying 死者. Q. What kind of casualties? A. Those which are due to accidents.

> 帰る時間は、曜日によって違います。
>   Going home time differs according to the day of the week.

In this sentence によって is just the て-form of による. It acts adverbially. Q. How does going home time differ? A. It differs according to the day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Stem form よる attaches to the following noun 死者.

> （事故による死者）が（増えている）。[Accident casualties *(casualties due to accidents)*] [are increasing].

☝Only speaks of accident casualties.

---

て-form creates a clause separation.

> （事故によって）（死者が増えている）。[Due to accidents] [casualties are increasing].

☝Speaks of total casualties (accidental and non-accidental).